# ProjectName.exe has triggered a breakpoint

Tags: c++, visual-studio, debugging, compiler-errors

when running the program it runs correctly but always throws this error. it says the error comes from the line:

```
int* temp = new int[length];
```

I don't know why this is occurring. the program returns the array in sorted ascending order but then throws the break point.

```
void mergeSort(int *a, int low, int high)
{
    if (low == high)
        return;
    int q = (low + high) / 2;
    mergeSort(a, low, q);
    mergeSort(a, q + 1, high);
    merge(a, low, q, high);
}

void merge(int *a, int low, int q, int high)
{
    const int length = high - low + 1;
    int* temp = new int[length];
    int i = low;
    int k = low;
    int j = q + 1;

    while (i <= q && j <= high)
    {
        if (a[i] <= a[j])
            temp[k++] = a[i++];
        else
            temp[k++] = a[j++];
    }
    while (i <= q)
        temp[k++] = a[i++];
    while (j <= high)
        temp[k++] = a[j++];
    for (i = low; i <= high; i++)
        a[i] = temp[i];
}
```

Comment: Where's your `main` function? Please include a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Maybe length gets negative under some circumstance? Either use a debugger or provide a MRE ;) Unrelated, but you never free temp, which causes a memory leak.

Comment: When it hits the breakpoint go into the debugger and inspect the value of `length`.  If as we expect it is very large or negative inspect the values used to calculate it.  Debugging is a basic programming task and one you will need to become competent at.

Answer (score 0):

I think that is memory access violation on `temp`

```
    int k = low;
```

In `void merge` `k` varible is `temp` array index. If `mergeSort(a, q + 1, high)` calling than`merge low` argument is `q + 1` and `k` is out of range 0 ~ length.

If `k` is out of range 0 ~ length. `temp[k]` is occured access violation.
I also suggest that add `delete[] temp` in `merge` function.
This is my code

```
int _a[] = { 5, 1, 3, 4, 2 }; // Test array!

void merge(int *a, int low, int q, int high)
{
    const int length = high - low + 1;
    int* temp = new int[length];
    int i = low;
    int k = 0;   // I fixed it(low -> 0)
    int j = q + 1;

    while (i <= q && j <= high)
    {
        if (a[i] <= a[j])
            temp[k++] = a[i++];
        else
            temp[k++] = a[j++];
    }
    while (i <= q)
        temp[k++] = a[i++];
    while (j <= high)
        temp[k++] = a[j++];
    for (i = low; i <= high; i++)
        a[i] = temp[i];

    delete[] temp; // Add Delete
}

int main()
{
    mergeSort(_a, 0, 5);
    return 0;
}
```